# Google Charts not appearing using new loader library but works fine with old loader library

Tags: php, google-visualization, data-visualization

Solution: Spelling error in at loading my loader.js after checking browser console.

Currently, I am showing Google Charts through the old loader library (jsapi) while populating the charts with data from MySQL using PHP.

However, due to the need of calling SetOnLoadCallback multiple times which the old library can't do, I will need to convert to the loader.js in order to do that.

Problem is, when I switched to loader.js, none of my charts are showing, just blank. Below is my code for the PHP and Charts.

Here is my current code using old library loader.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
    //google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});

    //Chart (Hardest Topics decided by Students)
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart)

    //google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {

        // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);
        var options = {
            title: '',
            is3D: 'true'
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    //Chart1 (Total Value of Students Frustration and Boredness)
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart1)
    //google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart1);
    function drawChart1() {

        // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable1?>);

        var options = {
            title: 'Students Frustration and Boredness Value',
            is3D: 'true'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div1'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

Here is my code for the new chart.

```
            <!-- Google Chart -->
            <script type="text/javascript" sec="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">

            google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});

            //Chart (Hardest Topics decided by Students)
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart)
            function drawChart() {
            // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);
            var options = {
            title: '',
            is3D: 'true'
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

            //Chart1 (Total Value of Students Frustration and Boredness)
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart1)
            function drawChart1() {
            // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable1?>);
            var options = {
            title: 'Students Frustration and Boredness Value',
            is3D: 'true',
            legend: 'left'
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div1'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
            }
            </script>
            <!-- Google Chart end-->
```

Here is my PHP that gets the data used to populate my charts

```
            <?php
            $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password") or die("Failed to connect with database");
            mysqli_select_db($con, "tutor");

            //MySQL query start
            $sql="SELECT * 
            FROM googlechart";

            $sql1="SELECT username, sum(frustratedINT), sum(boredINT)
            FROM `selfreportfrustration`
            WHERE frustrated = 'Y' OR bored = 'Y'
            GROUP BY username";
            //MySQL query end
            //Result start
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
            $result1 = mysqli_query($con,$sql1) or die(mysqli_error($con));
            //Result end
            //Rows start
            $rows = array();
            $rows1 = array();
            //Rows end
            $flag = true;

            //Table start
            $table = array();
            $table1 = array();
            //Table end
            //Table Column array start
            $table['cols'] = array(

            // Labels for your chart, these represent the column titles
            // Note that one column is in "string" format and another one is in "number" format as pie chart only required "numbers" for calculating percentage and string will be used for column title
            array('label' => 'Weekly Task', 'type' => 'string'),
            array('label' => 'Percentage', 'type' => 'number')

            );
            $table1['cols'] = array(
            array('label' => 'User', 'type' => 'string'),
            array('label' => 'Frustrated', 'type' => 'number'),
            array('label' => 'Bored', 'type' => 'number')
            );
            //Table Column array end
            //Table Row array start
            $rows = array();
            while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $temp = array();
            // the following line will be used to slice the Pie chart
            $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['weekly_task']);

            // Values of each slice
            $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['percentage']);
            $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
            }
            $rows1 = array();
            while($r1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
            $temp1 = array();
            $temp1[] = array('v' => (string) $r1['username']);

            $temp1[] = array('v' => (int) $r1['sum(frustratedINT)']);
            $temp1[] = array('v' => (int) $r1['sum(boredINT)']);
            $rows1[] = array('c' => $temp1);
            }
            //Table Row array end
            //Table Row start
            $table['rows'] = $rows;
            $table1['rows'] = $rows1;
            //Table Row end
            //json start
            $jsonTable = json_encode($table);

            $jsonTable1 = json_encode($table1);
            //echo $jsonTable;
            //json end
            ?>
```

Comment: any errors in the browser console? where is the ajax that gets the data?

Comment: I bet there are syntax errors.  The first draw function is not closed properly.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why I had problems with the Loader.js is because I spelt src as sec...

It was stupid, I should have checked the browser console. Took me only 3 minutes to solve it afterwards. Thank you both @WhiteHat and @dlaliberte